# How to configure log4j

Tags: spring-mvc, logging, log4j

How to configure log4j to show only my
 `log.debug("test log");` 
messages in console without other system generated information?
It's very disturbing when in small app your console is messed with tons of useless ( at least for me) information like 
DEBUG org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults: Getting BeanInfo for class [org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView]
my log4j.properties file:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, file
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `LoggerMatchFilter` and `DenyAllFilter` to restrict your logging appender to messages coming from your code only.

```
LoggerMatchFilter filter = new LoggerMatchFilter();
filter.setLoggerToMatch("Your.Root.Namespace");
filter.setAcceptOnMatch(true);
log4j.appender.stdout.addFilter(filter); // Match your messages only.
log4j.appender.stdout.addFilter(new DenyAllFilter()); // Don't match anything else.
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your application using log4j or yet to configure??
[log4j configure steps](http://www.codejava.net/coding/how-to-configure-log4j-as-logging-mechanism-in-java)

If already log4j is in use, change the logger level to ERROR 
Check whether your applications is using any xml configuration file for log4j or properties file so you can change in it.

[logger level configuration](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_logging_levels.htm) steps.